# Why is session.paired unavailable?

Tags: ios, swift2, watchconnectivity

In an iOS app, I've created a swift file named DataCoordinator with the following code:

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

class DataCoordinator: NSObject {
    func test(session:WCSession!) {
        if session.paired == true {
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build, I get this error:

> 'paired' is unavailable
>   'paired' has been explicitly marked unavailable here

This is in the iOS app and not the in the WatchOS app.  It works fine if I use the above code in a ViewController class.

Comment: Where is the session activation code ?